# How can I debug malicious form upload which gives error 500?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I currently have an upload form which looks like

```
<form action="/Upload/Registration?measurementId=139" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registrationfiles</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="MeasurementId" value="139"/>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input id="RadioSelection" name="RadioSelection" type="radio" value="0" />
                <label>or</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="RecordId[0]" value="375" />
                <input type="file" name="RegistrationFile[0]" />
            </div>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And I have two methods in `UploadController`:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Registration(int measurementId)
{
    [...]
    return View(registrationViewModel);
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Registration(RegistrationViewModel data, ICollection<int> RecordId, ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> RegistrationFile)
{
    [...]
}
```

When I access http://mySite.com/Upload/Registration?measurementId=139 I get the form (as expected), but when I submit it I get `Error 500 - (Internal Server Error)`.

What is the reason for this bug?

I've many breakpoints, but none gets hit. It only states "Error 500".

This is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2013 18:50:13 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

edit: When I remove the second method, I don't get an error 500. And I never get a [YSOD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YSOD).

Comment: Look the server response in FireBug. What does it show? Are you using some javascript?

Comment: 500 is usually caused by an exception server side, although if you run this locally you should get a YSOD and an exception stack trace.

Comment: Look at the response body, not the headers. When the server sends 500 status code there's a body of this response. What's inside?

Comment: What happens if you remove the parameters from your POST action one by one to see if it works? You might be able to pinpoint the problem this way.

Comment: What do you see if you enable Break on all exceptions in VS?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Even when I remove all elements from the form I get this error.

Comment: Does anything show up in the event viewer?

Comment: What if you start emptying the form now and removing the input fields one by one until you are left with a bare `<form>` element?

Comment: @SLaks: When I enable Break on all exceptions in VS I get "System.MissingMethodException" but "Source Not Available" and then "System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException". But those exceptions also appear on working pages.

Comment: After removing [Authorize] I don't get any exceptions after clicking on "save", but still error 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.config set customErrors to "On" and redirect to Error.cshmtl. You should do this only for fixing the 500 error and put it back to "Off" afterwards.

For further instructions see [Can't get defaultRedirect to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211911/cant-get-defaultredirect-to-work) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211961/1176596 .

One possible problem might be that one of your used Models in a View lacks a default constructor.
If so, you will get a MissingMethodException in your Error view.